My WebStorm auto imports firestore from "firebase/compat", not from "firebase/firestore"
When I try to import firebase modules, my WebStorm import them from "firebase/compat". Then I open Context Actions to find "Insert fooBar from "firebase/firestore" but there's nothing but "Insert import firebase ("firebase/compat", ...)"

I want WebStorm to auto-import Firestore modules from "firebase/firestore". Just to let you know if I add import statement directly the code works correctly. In the other project I could import firebase from "firebase/firestore" so I suppose the problem is my project configuration.
How can I fix this?
I added firebase to my WebStorm JavaScript Library Settings but nothing has changed.

